# Конвертирование PPTX в PNG при помощи python

Tags: python, ubuntu

Хочу конвертировать файл PPTX в изображение. Полистал инет, нашел только такие решения:

1. https://pypi.org/project/Aspose.Slides/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815883/python-pptx-export-img-png-jpeg

Что касается первого - поставил библиотеку, запустил - сохраняет, но кидает водяной знак.

Что касается второго, то это решение для Винды.

Поэтому ни одно ни второе - не подходит.

**Кто сталкивался с этим, может нашли обходной путь?**

Comment: Отредактируйте код библиотеки

Comment: Советуют обходной путь через pdf, смотрите <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523267/how-to-convert-pptx-files-to-jpg-or-png-for-each-slide-on-linux>

Comment: @Vad Sim, была тоже такая мысль, но ничего там такого не нашел..

Comment: https://github.com/jdhao/pptx_to_image  нужно будет подкорректировать немного.

Comment: @Сергей Кох, сделал по Вашей ссылке, но есть проблема со шрифтами...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем "чистое" решение, но вполне "временное/рабочее", имхо:

1. сконвертировать с помощью libreoffice в pdf
2. сконвертировать pdf в картинки с помощью Imagemagick

Проверял для Ubuntu18.04, без GUI.

Cтавим необходимые пакеты:

```bash
apt update && apt install libreoffice
apt install imagemagick
apt install ghostscript
```

Правим настройки imagemagick: в файле `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` находим строку `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />` и меняем настройку `<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />`

Конвертируем файл `test.pptx` в `test.pdf`

```bash
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.pptx
```

Конвертируем файл `test.pdf` в набор `*.jpg` файлов - постранично

```bash
convert -density 150 test.pdf -quality 80 output-%3d.jpg
```

Если делать с помощью Python - можно воспользоваться функцией `os.system()` или [почитать статью](https://www.the-analytics.club/python-shell-commands#:%7E:text=If%20you%20need%20to%20execute,arguments%20or%20producing%20text%20output.)

Более подробно эта методика описана например [здесь](https://jdhao.github.io/2020/03/30/pptx_to_image/)
Также похожая тема есть [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229782/export-all-slides-in-libreoffice-impress-to-pdf)

Как по мне идеально конвертируется из pdf в jpg, но немного меняются цвета/насыщение при конвертации из pptx в pdf.

Comment: Я тоже сделал через Libre Office, но проблема случилась в грязной конвертации. А именно - шрифты... Т.е. Libre Office не знает шрифтов и поэтому получается не совсем то, что нужно...

Comment: libreoffice 6 конвертит без ошибок, но "портит" немного цвета, libreoffice 7 у меня шрифты тоже не нашёл...  это под убунту. Под windows -всё ок.   Как вариант можно попробовать вот этот [способ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222348/how-to-export-slides-to-html-pdf-doc-in-google-slides-api). Возможно, если использование windows-сервера, виртуалки с windows - не вариант, то стоит поискать "платные" решения. Всё-таки pptx - это формат, которыё использует Microsoft, не факт что есть 100% рабочее опен-сорс решение.

Answer (score 2):

Для различных веб-интеграций можно реализовать следующим образом

1. Coздать аккаунт Azure
2. Создать приложение в Azure AD с scope Files.ReadWrite.All
3. Получить client id для Microsoft Flow / Power Automate
4. Открыть пользователю страницу авторизации (OAuth 2.0)
5. [Загрузить презентацию в OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online)
6. [Скачать презентацию указав формат jpg в запросе](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format?view=odsp-graph-online#http-request).

```
GET /drive/items/{item-id}/content?format=jpg
```

Увы, без Azure не выйдет оперировать с OneDrive. Для персонального пользования можно автоматизировать загрузку файлов в облако с помощью selenium/playwright, запуск предпросмотра в Office 365 и экспорт как jpg.